# Is there a sandbox to post test questions?

Tags: support, sandbox

I have noticed a behaviour that may or may not be a [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) bug. It is a discrepancy between the preview and the rendered result, which is why I would need to post a question to check it out.

Is there an official place to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Warning, do not enter this question using Opera.

Comment: @Gnoupi: Why not?

Comment: @Nyus - because at the time when I wrote this comment, one message on it was making it crash.

Comment: I believe it's also dangerous for mobile users due to an experiment with nested block quotes

Comment: Apart from being link-only answer, it doesn't answer the question, which is where to post test questions. Your answer suggest posting an answer, which is not the same as posting the question.

Comment: You cannot post test questions in the formatting sandbox.  That was the question, and this answer doesn't properly answer it.

Answer (score 13):

The formatting sandbox does not really fit as it can only accept **answers**, not questions.

So, such thing as "questions sandbox" is not really possible since what you really ask for is a sandbox site, which does not exist.

If you really must test posting a question just do it, make sure to make it clear it's just a test (do NOT post stuff like "sjksjdidjs") and **delete it asap** right after posting it to minimize the noise.

Answer (score 4):

It's not publicly accessible, but if you have [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) and your team is OK with posting test questions, you could use that. Of course, if your investigation does reveal a question-only Markdown renderer bug, you'll need to post it here anyway, but your experiments won't annoy other Meta Stack Exchange users.

Teams even has (limited) [API access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) so you might be able to use it as [a sandbox for read-only actions in apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328552/295232); it has a 14 day free trial mode.

This will not work to test out Winter Bash hats, as Winter Bash is disabled in internal Teams sites for privacy reasons.

Comment: If Stack Exchange Inc. deems use of a Teams trial for this purpose inappropriate, feel free to remove the last sentence and delete this comment.

Comment: Per [the doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams): "In addition to all **write methods**, the following... are **not supported** when specifying a Team with `?team=`". (But the `?team` is mandatory, isn't it?)

Comment: @AwesomePoodles I meant that you could create a question via the website, and check how it looks like in the API. But I'll clarify the answer to point that out.

Answer (score 3):

Why not try it on your question and then change it back when you are done? Can you not edit your own question?

If it works, maybe you could describe it and change this to a bug.

Comment: Cheers, that's the way I would have done it, but it turned out not to be a bug.

Comment: -1 Too many edits force posts into community wiki mode.

Comment: @nyuszika7h not anymore, it's now safe to edit as much as we want without risking of CW.