# Links to Stack Exchange questions should behave the same in comments as in posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

Links inside answers to other pages on Stack Exchange sites get automatically converted, but they don't get converted inside comments. I'd like to request that they get converted in comments, too.

Here's an example of this behavior:

> [image]

Comment: Alright this is why you did it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/is-there-a-sandbox-to-post-test-questions/182381#182381)(10k). But please use the actual sandbox next time.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments?rq=1

Comment: @Antony Yes I misread the first post where it said you needed reputation for community wiki edits to use the sandbox

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks, I did look for it but I couldn't find it

Comment: @durron597 The rep needed for CW edits is 100, not 20k for tag wiki edits. And you can always post an answer at 1 rep. Comments require only 1 rep here as well.

Comment: @Antony Not having a great day with this post :D Thanks

Comment: @Antony You need 100 rep to edit a CW post without needing review.  An anon user can still suggest an edit.  (Granted the OP does have more than 100 rep anyway.)  The question is also protected, so you need 10 rep to post an answer, not 1 (but the OP has more than 10 rep, so that wasn't his issue).

Comment: @Servy The issue was that I misread the question and didn't even try :)