# Two comments add if we press Enter twice

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

If we press `Enter` twice in comments then it add 2 comments in answer or question.

[image]

Get same error again

[image]

Javascript Console Output with one warning only.

[image]

Comment: Can't repro here.

Comment: Does the UI just display two comments until the page is refreshed? Or are two comments saved and displayed after a refresh?

Comment: Let me see it in action... nope, only one comment. There is also a server side check (rate limit) so can't see how this is possible.

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I see you also deleted your comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21991411/447356) so we can't really see if this was real bug or just design bug, as @StevenV mentioned before in a comment.

Comment: Let's see if I can reproduce

Comment: Nope, I can't. Can you add details - what browser? What OS? Any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Yesterday, I was able to reproduce this. But today i tried 2-3 times its not reproducible :(. I deleted my old comments because I dont want to confuse user :)..

Comment: Cannot reproduce...

Comment: You can check same on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067955/unpack-valueerror-in-python/22068028?noredirect=1#comment33464601_22068028 I added image to this question.

Comment: @Lafada you still have not told us what browser and OS you are using, and if you get any JS error.

Comment: I am using Chrome and Windows 7, For js error, will you please tell me how can I check that ?

Comment: You can open the developer tools in your browser by pressing *F12*. Now click on the *Console* tab and see if there are any messages there.

Comment: @Lafada Try to clear your cache. `F12 -> Settings -> Disable cache while Dev tools are opened -> F5 (refresh)`. Then try to reproduce the problem again.

Comment: @lonica I added new screenshot with JS Development tools console output.

Comment: I've seen keyboards (yes, it's dependent on physical, hardware keyboards) that fire keyboard events twice.

Comment: No repro on XP, FF 27.0.1. I think it really depends on something that's not really common, not OS or browser. Maybe hardware (as mentioned by bjb568) or plugin/extension. But still, there is comment rate limit which should be impossible to post successive comments.

Comment: @Oded isn't there server side rate limit for comments?

Comment: There is, @Shadow

Comment: Though, there are two comments there with the exact same timestamp by the OP. Could be a race where the second comment wasn't detected as a second comment. Looks super rare to me. And not that much of a problem, given these are comments which can easily be deleted.

Comment: @Oded but it *might* be used to abuse the system at some point (i.e. 1000 comments in a second by a troll) so isn't it better to seal the hole in the bucket before it's causing a major flood? :)

Comment: @Oded by the way, when I tried to check the server side rate limiting, I got 409 status code when trying to post two comments in the same time with client side script. Maybe this will help to debug?

Comment: Thanks for that, @Sha - will certainly help it tracking this down.

Comment: @Tim -  never reproduced. Even the OP couldn't reproduce this. As far as I know, there was no fix as it was never found.

Comment: @Oded a while back I posted a test question, and you said I shouldn't - and asked me where I'd instructions to say to. I didn't know where but I found it today - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244857/252153