# Throttle comment button to prevent double submission

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, rate-limiting

If you type in a comment, and then press enter very quickly in succession, you will produce two comments in succession. I wasn't able to get more than 2, but 2 is fairly easy.

[image]

Perhaps the enter button needs to prevent itself from sending for a small duration after the original press. I accidentally managed to do this on mSO earlier. It is fairly easy to reproduce.

Comment: Wat? I was just about to ask it! It never happened to me earlier, but happened *twice*  today.

Comment: Hm, so no repro then :(

Comment: Hm, so no repro then :(

Comment: Lol, @Travis :D

Comment: Lol, @Travis :D

Comment: Wow, they totally removed rate limiting. Now that's a nasty bug. +1 and retracted close vote, sorry!

Comment: @rene we used to be able to add comment only once in 15 seconds or so with annoying timer reset.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - To be honest that other one does describe the same behavior. Perhaps something changed server side that allows the behavior again.

Comment: We recently switched to a different throttling method. Thanks for finding a way to abuse it. :P Err... I mean, disabling accidental double-posting should be easy enough.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Should I just close this as a duplicate of the other one then?

Comment: @TravisJ What other one?

Comment: @TravisJ yep but it was marked no-repro already so better report again than try to revive IMO.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Shadow Wizard found a question highlighting the same behavior from a year ago, I missed it in my first search. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222780/two-comments-add-if-we-press-enter-twice

Comment: That one's a year old and (probably) a different issue. Just stick with this new report.

Comment: @Anna so no more rate limiting for comment upvoting?

Comment: @Sha for *upvoting* the limit was gone a long-long time ago

Comment: OK, time to update the faq then.

Comment: this is a test to reproduce the bug

Comment: this is a test to reproduce the bug (edit: yes, obviously, I can repro this)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I TOLD EVERYONE THEY'D [RUE THE DAY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFbaZkpue0Y) WHEN COMMENT THROTTLES WERE REMOVED.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: This should now be fixed.

Comment: So the new throttling is 3 comments per 25 seconds, right? Can you please confirm?

Comment: 3 per 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, and no throttling/limit on votes, right?

Comment: Correct; upvotes, undo upvotes, and delete votes no longer have a throttle, other than their daily limits.

Comment: Cool!  I see edit is still rate limited to 5 seconds, without the annoying timer reset. Awesome!