# Is there a sandbox to play with Stack Overflow API?

Tags: feature-request

Just trying to figure it out without spamming the website. There really should be something to allow people to learn the API.

Comment: @Servy That's not the same thing.

Comment: Maybe you could use the Formatting Sandbox to do your changing requests.

Comment: I know, but it answers the question.  If it *really* bothers you, you can just close it as a dup of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/is-there-a-sandbox-to-post-test-questions/39111#39111) instead.