# Would a practice area for question and comment formatting be useful for newbies?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, sandbox

Would it be useful for newbies to have an area for practicing question and comment formatting?

I am thinking of 2 different areas - 1 for each purpose. I think *I* need it...

Every time (so far) that I've answered a question or added comments, it is a struggle to get the formatting right. Usually I go to re-edit the answer and once, I've collided with some helpful soul, who was trying to "fix" my answer.

Comment: That's nice. . .There is the sandbox. Do you actually have a question?

Comment: There is a practice area—the insta-rendered preview below the editor.

Comment: Are you looking for this:[Is there a sandbox to post test questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39109/201151)

Comment: yes, I was. tx to you and ᔕᖺᘎᕊ

Comment: @grgarside, I do not consider the preview box a practice area. It is a feedback area - yes. I would prefer to know the formating rules before I start answering a question. Several times I got stuck on formating long enough for somebody else to post the SAME answer before me.

Comment: Additionally, you can write a new question or answer without submitting, and see the formatting change in the preview under the input box.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Re your edit: What was wrong with "practising"? ("practicing" is a noun, the verb is "practising" ;)

Comment: @James hmmm. I always thought it should be 'practicing'... although a quick google shows 'practising' is British... and I'm British...! Anyway that wasn't my main edit reason - the tags were annoying me! Feel free to re-edit ;P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Nah, question is dead. I just knew your were UK, so wondered why. I believe US use "practicing" universally, so probs suit more people this way. If I have to live with "help center" I can live with this :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want already exists: [Formatting Sandbox](/q/3122).

You can 'answer' over there to test out post formatting, however you need to get 10 reputation *on **this** site* - but that isn't too hard - suggest 5 good edits/get 2 question upvotes/1 answer upvote and your past the limit.

Once you've answered over there, you can add a comment to your new answer, where you can test comment formatting :)

---

Although, what you mention is not really a problem - all comments have a 5 minute period where you can edit the comment, and all posts can be edited whenever you want (if you do it within 5 minutes, it won't even create a revision!). There's nothing wrong in correcting yourself! Make mistakes and learn from them :)

By the way, if you're unsure on any formatting related thing, see the [Markdown editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) - it's easy to understand and there are examples for everything.

Comment: It looks like a lot of people new about the sandbox. Since this question is not really useful, can I delete it? Should I delete it?

Comment: @gene You can't delete now there is an upvoted answer. I've voted to close as dupe. You can use your vote to complete that, or let others vote. Either way it'll eventually be closed :) (Having dupes is not always a bad thing, as they provide different searchable keywords to reach the same end question/answers, tho it's better to not create then if can be helped)

Comment: @James, - I agree as you can now see. :-) tx all.